# Why do we consider the ground state as the lowest energy state?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, ground-state

According to Bohr's theory, electrons move around the atom in orbits having specific energy. When it absorbs energy, it gets excited to higher energy states. In H2 atom, ground state is -13.6 eV while other states have energy values: -3.4 eV, -1.51 eV and so on. But the modulus of these values are 13.6, 3.4, 1.51 etc, which means that ground state has the highest energy. Then why do we consider the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have heard and read, potential energy is calculated with respect to a reference. In the case of Bohr's theory, the reference is a point at infinite distance from the nucleus and the potential there is taken to be $0$.

So as the electron moves closer and closer to the nucleus it's potential decreases because the nucleus is positively charged and the electron is negatively charged. That is why the values are negative.

Coming to your question of why the ground state is the lowest energy state, well we don't compare the modulus of potential energy when it comes to checking which is the lowest, we compare it along with the sign and thus $-13.6\ eV$ is the lowest energy state.

PS: The reference which has to be chosen is completely up to the person who is doing the calculations. So one might pick the ground state of the electron to be the reference for potential. In this case the potential of the states would be $\ 0\ eV,\ 9.2\ eV,\ 12.09\ eV$ and so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The negative sign is there purely to tell us that the electron is bound so that in order to free it, it would require an energy of +13.6 eV.  This state 1s requires the most amount of energy to liberate it.